# Where is crab cove?

Tags: mino-monsters

In the game Mino Monsters for iOS, one of the goals on The Windward Beach is to find Crab Cove. I've searched everywhere, and I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Beach Back Road, backroad is a flashing step.  In there you will find a different flashing step towards the top and that's crab cove. :)

Comment: Thanks!  The flashing step was key. For posterity, up till wall (a few steps), then go right and follow left wall, take 1st left branch , then next right branch, then next right branvh(around pool). Follow to first flashing step. Inside back beach road go up and take first right branch, hug top wall and take first left branch as you continue to go up.  If you want count the steps, it would make the answer even better. Why is that place buried so deep. Sheesh.

Comment: Wheres beachbackroad? I cant seem to find a way to enfer it or find it